# Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить ошибку? Язык JS вообще не знаю, программу требуется написать в рамках курса по графике (OpenJSCAD)

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(){ 

var c1 = CSG.sphere({ 
radius: (round(10*sin(14))/10),
center: [0,0,0] }); 

var c2 = CSG.sphere({ 
radius: (round(10*sin(14))/10), 
center: [1.5*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0] 
});

var c3 = CSG.sphere({ 
radius: (round(10*sin(14))/10), 
center: [2*1.5*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0] 
});

var c4 = CSG.sphere({ 
radius: (round(10*sin(14))/10), 
center: [3*1.5*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0]
});

return [c1, c2, c3, c4];
}());
```

Ошибка:
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
Line: 57,col: 4

Comment: Если не знаете JS, то придётся хотя бы читать то, что вам пишут. Ошибка "missing ) after argument list Line: 57,col: 4" прямым говорит что на строке 57, в списке аргументов, не хватает закрывающей скобки. В приведённом коде всегго 24 строки и все скобки на месте, соответсвенно вам нужно смотреть к какому именно файлу относится данная ошибка. Обычно это подчёркнутый текст справа сверху от ошибки([пример](https://imgur.com/LbRaSdf)), но всё зависит  от того где вы выполняете задание

Comment: Да вот, да, я прочитала, что не хватает скобки, но в коде меньше строк, потому и в замешательстве и решила задать вопрос))

Comment: Перенаправляет на тот же редактор, в новую вкладку. Если у Вас откроется, то:
https://files.openedu.ru/compgr/lab-cg/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Тут проблема исполнения сервиса.

Код, который вы вводите, они вставляют:

```
pos = function(p) {o.push(p);}; 
pos(union(/*Вот сюда*/));
```

Поэтому точку с запятой тут ставить никак нельзя, уберите её.

Порекомендовал бы вам использовать функциональный подход, вместо IIFE:

```
[
    [15*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0],
    [15*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0],
    [20*1.5*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0],
    [30*1.5*round(10*sin(14))/10,0,0]
].map((center) => CSG.sphere({ 
    radius: (round(100*sin(14))/10), 
    center 
})).concat([
    CSG.sphere({radius: 10, center: [-10, -10, -10]})
])
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Убрала точку с запятой и всё заработало! Спасибо!)